# Where clause in Model.all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby and have the following:

```
students = Student.all(:order => "score DESC",
            :limit => 5)
```

However I want to put a where clause into this as well but I get the error "Unknown key: where". My `student` table references an `exam` table (`t.references :exam`) which has a `date` field so I need to do something like:

```
students = Student.all(:where => "exam.date='01/01/2012'",
                       :order => "score DESC",
                       :limit => 5)
```

How do I use a `where` clause in the `all` method and is `exam.date='01/01/2012'` correct ?

Comment: Take a read of the [guide at ROR](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-all) method with arguments is a pre-Rails 3 API, and `all(*args)` is equivalent to [`find(:all, *args)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find), which takes the `:conditions` option:

```
students = Student.all(:conditions => "exam.date='01/01/2012'",
                       :order => "score DESC",
                       :limit => 5)
```

It is generally preferred to use Rails 3's chain-able relation methods, though:

```
students = Student.where("exam.date='01/01/2012'").order('score DESC').limit(5)
```

Comment: Nearly works. I get `no such column: meeting.date` Do I need to do anything different when dealing with references in a where clause?

Comment: If you're trying to reference a different table then you'll of course have to do an `includes` or `joins`. You'd have to do with same with `all` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `#where` method:

```
students = Students.where('exam.date = ?', '01/01/2012').all(order: 'score DESC', limit: 5)
```